# Get the link inside href selenium python3

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get the link href with python and selenium. The href url is `<a target="_blank" href="https://click.discord.com/ls/click?upn=RANDOMNUMBERSANDLETTERS" style="text-decoration:none;line-height:100%;background:#5865f2;color:white;font-family:Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:15px;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;margin:0px;"> Verify Email </a>` I want to get the full discord link but I have no idea how.
I am using a website called https://www.mohmal.com/en/inbox to get the value inside href.
I already tried using `link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Verify Email')]").get_attribute('href') print(link)` but it returned the website url instead of the link inside href.
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: This `link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Verify Email')]").get_attribute('href') print(link)` return you `https://click.discord.com/ls/click?upn=RANDOMNUMBERSANDLETTERS` what is your desired output  ?

Comment: It returns the website url: ```https://www.mohmal.com/en/inbox```

Comment: That's not ideal behavior.. please put some delay and make sure `//a[contains(text(),'Verify Email')]` is unique element in HTMLDOM.

Comment: I inouted delay but still the same issue. I found 2 other elements with the text "Verify Email Address for Discord" maybe thats the issue? 1 of them is a href= with the value as the website url im getting and the other is just a div.

Comment: Can you share html for all three of them ?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/1wdr16w https://prnt.sc/1wdr0dh https://prnt.sc/1wdqytb

Comment: Go to HTMLDOM  by Pressing Press F12 in Chrome -> go to element section -> do a CTRL  + F -> then paste  and see `//a[contains(text(),'Verify Email')]` if your desired element is getting highlighted with 1/1 matches  ?

Comment: Its showing 2 elements which the first one is the website url and the second one is the link i need

Comment: Please see below

Answer (score 0):

Please use this xpath :

```
(//a[contains(text(),'Verify Email')])[2]
```

**In code :**

```
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Verify Email')])[2]").get_attribute('href')
print(link)
```

Comment: Nope, still getting the no element found error.

Comment: Wait there wasn't any error before.. check in html dom for unique element you may have to adjust [2] to [1] and so on..